# On modules whose quotient by any non-zero submodule is not isomorphic to the original module

Tags: reference-request, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, modules

Let $M$ be an $R$-module ($R$ commutative ring with unity) such that for every non-zero submodule $N$ of $M$ , $M/N$ is not isomorphic to $M$; then what can we say about $M$? Can we say $M$ is finitely generated? If in general $M$ is not finitely generated, then does some condition on $R$ implies $M$ is finitely generated? I am only able to prove that if $M$ is free then $M$ is finitely generated. Please help.
thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example that's not finitely generated.

Let $R=\mathbb{Z}$ and
$$M=\bigoplus_{p\text{ prime}}\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}.$$

Then $M$ has elements of order $p$ for every prime $p$, but if $N$ is a non-zero submodule, then for some prime $p$, $M/N$ has no elements of order $p$, so $M\not\cong M/N$.

Or, again with $R=\mathbb{Z}$, take $M=\mathbb{Q}$. Every non-zero group endomorphism of $\mathbb{Q}$ is an isomorphism, so it's not isomorphic to a proper quotient of itself.

Comment: This can be generalized to any ring having infinitely many simple modules, because a decomposition into a direct sum of simple modules “complements direct summands”.

Comment: @Jeremy Rickard : Thanks for the example . Do you know of any conditions on $R$ which forces any such $M$ to be finitely generated ?

Comment: @users The only examples I've thought of are artinian rings of finite representation type (i.e., with only finitely many isomorphism classes of indecomposable modules). Then any module $M$ is a direct sum of copies of the indecomposables, and if the module is not finitely generated then some indecomposable $N$ must occur infinitely often as a direct summand, and so $M\cong M\oplus N$ and $M$ is isomorphic to a proper quotient of itself.

Comment: @users I've added an even more elementary example.

Comment: @JeremyRickard : Thanks for your second example . I believe that if $R$ is any integral domain , and $F$ its field of fractions , then $F$ is indeed Hopfian as an $R$-module right ? And since $F$ cannot be finitely generated as an $R$-module unless $R$ itself is a domain , so this gives another large family of counterexamples ...

Comment: @JeremyRickard : Sorry , that should have been " The fraction field of a domain $R$ cannot be a finitely generated module over $R$ unless $R$ itself is a 'field' " ...

Comment: @users In fact, even if $R$ has a quotient ring that is a domain but not a field, the field of fractions of that quotient is an example, so there are infinitely generated Hopfian modules for any commutative ring with Krull dimension greater than zero. And as egreg points out, my first example generalizes to any ring with infinitely many simple modules. So that leaves zero dimensional semilocal rings.